# Unable to feed mini-batch to Tensorflow input placeholder - Tensorflow 1.3.0

Tags: tensorflow, mini-batch

Can anyone tell me why I can’t feed mini-batch of data to my inputs `tf.nn.placeholder`? Did something change lately because it've worked for me for whole last year?

Error:

`Cannot feed value of shape (1024, 784) for Tensor 'nn_inputs:0', which has shape '(?, 768)'`

And my inputs `tf.nn.placeholder` is:

```
inputs_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 768], name="nn_inputs")
```

Comment: "Cannot feed value of shape (1024, **784**) for Tensor 'nn_inputs:0', which has shape '(?, **768**)'"...

Comment: Oh wow.... I can't read. Thanks